# Using capture groups to find words on different lines

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I'm working on a script to swap the first occurences of two words with each other in a file using sed.

The sed command looks like this `sed -E 's/(github.com) (github-secondary)/\2 \1/g' ~/.ssh/config`

The command isn't working and I believe the reason is because the capture groups are on different lines. How do I specify that there can be any amount of spacing between the capture groups?

Sample Input:

```
hi
hi
github.com
github.com
j
x
github-secondary
ljlk
lkjfds
```

Simple Output:

```
hi
hi
github-secondary
github.com
j
x
github.com
ljlk
lkjfds
```

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus updated the question

Comment: sed operates on lines, not whole files.

Comment: @Jens whats the best solution for whole files?

Comment: @Jens Im pretty sure that sed does work with files, i have seen it myself. Also the expression doesnt work in http://regexr.com/

Comment: @stack_pooper What I meant was that the default pattern space sed operates on is lines, not the whole file. I.e. it processes a file line by line. But you seem to want to swap some words across newlines. That's notoriously more involved. See my solution with perl for a different approach.

Comment: You should include a 2nd instance of `github-secondary` in your example as right now you're getting answers that will produce the expected output you show but do not do what you said you wanted which is to swap the **first occurrence** of each string.

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier with perl, which has better support for dealing with multi-line input. In your case:

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/(github\.com)(.*)(github-secondary)/$3$2$1/s' x
hi
hi
github-secondary
github.com
j
x
github.com
ljlk
lkjfds
```

The -0777 tells perl to treat the whole file as a single record. The `/s` says to treat newlines not specially, so `(.*)` matches as many characters/lines as it can.

Answer (score 0):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. You don't need capture groups or to read your whole file into memory to get the output you want from the input you posted though:

```
$ awk '
    !x{x=sub(/github-secondary/,"github.com")}
    !y{y=sub(/github\.com/,"github-secondary")}
1' file
hi
hi
github-secondary
github.com
j
x
github.com
ljlk
lkjfds
```

If that's not adequate then edit your question to show more truly representative sample input and expected output and clarify your requirements.

Comment: hey awesome this worked, can you add a simple explanation

Comment: Sure - if you haven't done the first replacement, do it and set a flag x to remember you've done it, and if you haven't done the second replacement then do it and set a flag y to remember you've done that.